# c# keyword this

Tags: c#

I understand that keyword "this" refers to the variables outside constructor within a class variables. but why not just change name of parametor to (string _name, string _alias) , all the example of "this" in tutorials just states the obvious, but i'd like to know the working use of why this keyword is needed in a certain situation.

```
private string name;
private string alias;
   public Employee(string name, string alias) 
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.alias = alias;
    }
```

Comment: See [this (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx).

Comment: You will not be able to tell the difference from the parameter and class fields otherwise? You can name them _name, but it is not "pretty", and say "_name = name"

Comment: This is just naming convention.. Please look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28VS.71,classic%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you could put an underscore on your field names so `this` is not needed (it would still be allowed, but not needed, as it can be inferred if there is no clash with a local variable).  In fact, Microsoft's standards encourage doing so.

However, there are still plenty of cases where you may need the `this` keyword.

One example is if you had a utility in another class which accepted an `Employee`, such as:

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static void SomeMethod(Employee employee)
    {
    }
}
```

and you wanted to call this utility from within the `Employee` class, you would have to call it as `Utility.SomeMethod(this);`.

Also, extension methods called on the current instance must be prefaced by `this.`.  Given the following extension method:

```
public static class UtilityExtensionMethods
{
    public static void SomeExtensionMethod(this Employee employee)
    {
    }
}
```

if you wanted to call this extension method from within the `Employee` class, you would have to call it as `this.SomeExtensionMethod();`.

Answer (score 1):

I name *private member variables* `_x` to avoid such cases<sup>1</sup>. [Arguments for/against this abound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1630928/166390).

```
private string _name;
public Employee(string name, string alias) 
{       
   // Equivalent to `this._name = name`, as _name is not shadowed
   _name = name;
}
```

On the other hand, I am *opposed* to naming parameters `_x` because *parameter names are part of the public contract*<sup>2</sup>. This contract should be clean, stable, and should *not* be dictated by the internal implementation which includes member variable names.

In the past I used names like `employeeName`, `aName`, and `theAlias` for parameters in such cases, but I disliked the artificial modifiers that ended up being used. If I could not use underscores for private variables I would use `this.x` and not think twice about it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Requiring this form is due to `this` being "implicit" in C# and variable shadowing. That is, `this.x` is needed because `x` will refer to a local variable/parameter, should it exist - and it does here.

```
private string name;
public Employee(string name, string alias) 
{
   // Re-assignes parameter to itself.
   // Does NOT assign member variable!
   name = name;
}
```

<sup>2</sup> I believe that underscore in names break "CLS-compatibility", but that is not a concern for me, and only using this convention for *private* member variables avoids exposing such incompatible names publicly.

Comment: Acconding the guidelines of from Microsoft they are agains prefixing the fields.. `Do not apply a prefix to field names or static field names. Specifically, do not apply a prefix to a field name to distinguish between static and nonstatic fields. For example, applying a g_ or s_ prefix is incorrect.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta31s3bc%28VS.71%29.aspx, but many users (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630844/c-sharp-member-variables-fields-naming-convention) prefix.. I am against prefix.. ;-)

Comment: @TryingToImprove I would not use `g_` or `s_`. That is clearly wrong (to me), especially when to denote between static/non-static. `m_` is just too noisy, but I find `_` for *private member variables* just right. I actually added the [excerpts to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1630928/166390), and follow [the linked article guidelines](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices) :D

Comment: I dont argue with you :-) I can see the pro/cons for doing so. I prefix "privates" in JavaScript with `_`. But in C# my privates are camelCase and public are CamelCase. I can't remember last time I had to have a "public" field.